# INSERT or UPDATE, but not sure I can have duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

Creating a bit of a bookmark system. Users can bookmark or un-bookmark players to follow.  On the surface, I thought a duplicate key update would work with the playerID.  However, a player might have several Users bookmark him.

So it would have to pair up playerID to userID.  If that pair doesn't exist, INSERT.  If that pair does exist, UPDATE.

Below is what I had for the duplicate key update.  How would I go about checking a pairing of two columns?  Concat?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO a_player_bookmark (playerID,bookmark,userID,username)
                        VALUES ('". $pid ."','". $bookmark ."','". $userID ."','". $user ."')
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY
                        UPDATE bookmark = '". $bookmark ."'

                        ";
```

Comment: Likely would be best to keep two separate (and indexed) table views of the underlying data table, that way you can easily see who you follow and who follows you. That said, you'll need to make an association in the data table of `follower` -> `followed`, and that's strictly unidirectional so you can make a compound unique key of the two columns together. Then you can make use of upsert.

Comment: I don't fully follow what you're saying.  What about IF EXISTS?

Comment: `insert ... on duplicate key update` is an upsert (update insert). Are you asking what if the value is already in the table? that'd be the benefit of the unique key. Also, even if you're starting out I'd recommend using PDO and learning about prepared statements, concatenating your values into the query is a big no-no for security reasons.

Comment: playerID and userID are unique keys in other data tables, and I have this bookmark table where I am associating a follower and followed.     I need help with a query that checks if the relationship exists to determine if I need to insert or update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so relate each column via a foreign key (for completeness' sake), and then make a unique key over *2 columns*, both the `playerID` (follower) and `userID` (followed). Then you can have `a -> b`, and `b -> a`, but adding it again will cause a duplicate key error. This allows you to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE follower=follower` to skip inserting, or `bookmark = VALUES(bookmark)` to update the bookmark value.

I've also renamed your table `bookmarks` for brevity.

```
-- the sql query (plain text / string)
INSERT INTO bookmarks (playerID, bookmark, userID, username)
    VALUES (:playerID, :bookmark, :userID, :username)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bookmark = VALUES(bookmark)
```

Now within PHP, I've demonstrated the basic concepts of running a prepared statement with PDO. If you're not willing to do PDO then you can just concatenate into the query accordingly (replacing the placeholders yourself), but I strongly discourage it.

```
//within php
$con = /* a PDO connection reference, see PDO docs for creating one */;
$query = /* our earlier statement, in string form */;
$stmt = con->prepare($query); //creates a PreparedStatement
//bind our values to the placeholders in the sql statement
$stmt->bindValue(':playerID', $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':bookmark', $bookmark, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userID', $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(); //run the query
$updated = $stmt->rowCount(); //number of updated rows
```

Moving forward, I would drop `username` as a column (seems redundant, why not just reference the users table to get the name?), and then depending on the purpose of `bookmark` I would potentially even forsake that.

But before any of this, you need to ensure the proper keys are on your table.

```
-- I suggest removing any existing constraints beforehand
-- Relate playerID to the users table
ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_follower` FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
-- Relate userID to the users table
ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_followed` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
-- Relate username to the users table, if you decide to keep it
ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_followed_name` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
-- Add your UNIQUE KEY for the two columns defining the relationship, aka a composite key
ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD UNIQUE INDEX `following` (`playerID`, `userID`)
```

Comment: That worked out!  I'm learning this stuff on the fly, so creating indexes was a new concept for me.   `Thank you`.   The `username` is more of a visual for me.  It's not used.